# Sprite kit touch and hold with swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, touch

i'm try to make my first game in sprite kit using swift

everything work fine for now but i couldn't know how could handle touch and hold in the screen

i'm try to make a jump power when the player hold the touch but i can't find event for this

thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)  {
 // action when the user touches the screen 
 // you can know where did he touch the screen like this
let touchLocation = touches?.anyObject().locationInView(self/* or your view */) 
}
override func touchesMoved(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
   // your code here 
}
override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
       // your code here
}
```

those method will help cary touches events in your screen

Comment: thanks Mohamed ,i know this method but how i could do touch and hold !!

Comment: i think you can deal with those method for touchesHold, for example
set a property of type bool in your gameScene , and set it to true in touchesBegan and touchesMoved and set it to false in touchesEnded, so you could know when you should make that jump power.
I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you need to handle 2 situations
1 - player taps on the screen/node - e.g. to jump
2 - player taps and holds - e.g. to change jump power

I think you need to handle both "touchesBegan" and "touchesEnded".
In "touchesBegan" start special timer and after some delay (e.g. 0.5 secs) start playing special animation for it (jump power indicator that shows current jump power)
on "touchesEnded" - stop timer, stop animation and calculate result jump power (based on timer's value).

If you also need to handle direction (angle) of jump - in this case you should also handle "touchesMoved" and calculate current angle based on touch position.